# Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 2'

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Google Kubernetes Engine running and I'm trying to deploy a mongo container. Everything works fine except when I try to use the argument "--wiredTigerCacheSizeGB", then the deployment fails because this command is not recognized. I'm using the latest Mongo version (5.0) and I see nothing in the documentation saying that this should not work.

Here is the yml configuration of the POD creation:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      environment: test
      role: mongo
  serviceName: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        environment: test
        role: mongo
      namespace: default
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - mongod
        - --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 2
        image: mongo:5.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: mongo
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data/db
          name: mongo-persistent-storage
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoSchedule
        key: dedicated
        operator: Equal
        value: backend
  updateStrategy:
    type: OnDelete
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      annotations:
        volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: standard
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: mongo-persistent-storage
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 20Gi
      volumeMode: Filesystem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it work if you remove the `--wiredTigerCacheSizeGB` flag?

<strike>I would be surprised.</strike>

> It does appear to work (see below) but I can't explain why. I am surprised!

If this is the correct [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/5.0/Dockerfile) for the image, then it uses a Docker `CMD` to run `mongod`.

If so, you'd need to run the image on Kubernetes using `args` not `command` in order to correctly override the container image's `CMD` and **not** override the container image's `ENTRYPOINT`, i.e.

```
containers:
- name: mongo
  args:
  - mongod
  - --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB=2
```

> **NOTE** The inclusion of `=` between the flag and value to avoid introducing YAML parsing issues.

I tested this hypothesis using `podman`; you can replace `podman` with `docker` in what follows if you use `docker`:

```sh
# Does not work: Override `ENTRYPOINT` with mongod+flag
# This is effectively what you're doing
podman run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
--entrypoint="mongod --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB=2" \
docker.io/mongo:5.0 \
Error: executable file `mongod --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB=2` not found in $PATH:
No such file or directory:
OCI runtime attempted to invoke a command that was not found

# Works: Override `CMD`
# This is what I thought should work
podman run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
docker.io/mongo:5.0 \
  mongod \
  --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB=2

# Works: Override `ENTRYPOINT` w/ mongod
# This is what I thought wouldn't work
podman run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
--entrypoint=mongod \
docker.io/mongo:5.0 \
  --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB=2
```

Comment: Thank you, the args did the job